# How to retain jQuery & Bootstrap functionality with no-refresh page loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

## Problem

I'm currently implementing non-refresh page loading in my website, and I am using ajax to load the page accordingly to the content section of my website when a user selects a page on the sidebar.

However, when I try to load a page, it loses all of its Bootstrap functionality (such as drop-downs, toggleables, etc') and the DataTables don't load either.

**Example:** I have a function that adds the class 'active' to the initial tab which works if I load the page through the URL.

However, it does not seem to get called through the dynamic page loading method that gets triggered when a person clicks on the page on the menu. Also, the DataTables won't load.

This is the no-refresh page-loading part after attempts to remedy the issue:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[name=user], a[name=moderator], a[name=admin], a[name=groups]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $.get('preloader.html', function(html) {
        $("#inner_content").append(html);
    });
    if(location.pathname != href) {
        loadContent( '#css', href, '#css' );
        loadContent( '#script_elements', href, '#script_elements' );
        window.history.pushState('page2', 'Title', href);
    }   
    loadContent( '#inner_content', href, '#inner_content' );            
});

//Content Loading Function
function loadContent(target, url, selector) {           
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(data,status,jqXHR) {
            $(target).empty();          
           $(target).html($(data).find(selector).addBack(selector).children());
        }
    });
}
```

The structure of the page that should be loaded is something along those lines (blade):

```html
@extends('user.layouts.main')
@section('extra_css')
 <style>
  /* Safari */
  @-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
  }
  
  .dataTables_length !important {
   margin-left:20px;
  }
  
  @keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
  }
  .colorpicker-alpha {display:none !important;} .colorpicker{ min-width:128px !important;}
 </style>
@endsection
@section('title', 'Group')
@section('content')
 <div class="row" id="content">
  <div class="col">
   <div class="tabs tabs-dark rounded-0 shadow">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#group1" name="groupSelector" data-toggle="tab" value="{{ $user->group->id }}">{{ $user->group->name }}</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
     <div class="tab-pane" id="group1">
      <div id="#{{ $user->id }}" class="tab-pane active ">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-12">
         <section class="card">
          <header class="card-header">     
           <div class="card-actions">
           
            <a href="#" class="card-action-loader" style="display: none;" name="loader"></a>
            
            <div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
             <a class="dropdown-item text-1 popup-with-zoom-anim ws-normal" href="#chooseRole">Choose Role</a>
             <a class="dropdown-item text-1" href="#" id="admin">Admin</a>
             <a class="dropdown-item text-1" href="#" id="moderator">Moderator</a>
             <a class="dropdown-item text-1" href="#" id="user">User</a>
            </div>
            <i id="loading" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-fw"></i>
            <a href="#" class="card-action-toggle" data-card-toggle></a>             
           </div>
          </header>
          <div class="card-body pt-0" style="margin-top:-13px;">
           <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="{{ $user->id }}" style="border: 1px solid #E3E4E7;" name="usersTable">
            <thead>
             <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>{!! __('groups.user') !!}</th>
              <th>{!! __('groups.rank') !!}</th>
              <th>{!! __('groups.lastOn') !!}</th>
              <th>{!! __('groups.activity') !!}</th>
              <th>{!! __('groups.xyz') !!}</th>
              <th></th>
             </tr>
            </thead>
           </table>
          </div>
         </section>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
@endsection
@section('bottom_elements')  
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() { 
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var usersTable = $('table[name=usersTable]#' + id).DataTable({
     autoWidth: false,
     "processing": true,
     "serverSide": true,
     "paging": true,
     "fnInitComplete": function() { 
      $('#loading').hide();
     },
     "order": [ 2, 'desc' ],
     dom: "<'row mt-0 mb-0 pt-4 pb-0'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5 pt-0 mb-0 pb-0 'B<'pt-3 mt-4 mb-0'l>><'col-sm-12 mt-4 mb-0 pt-0 col-md-7'p>>",
     "buttons": [
      {
       extend:    'copyHtml5',
       text:      '<i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>',
       titleAttr: 'Copy'
      },
      {
       extend:    'csvHtml5',
       text:      '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i>',
       titleAttr: 'CSV'
      }
     ],
     "ajax":{
      "url": "/groups/populate",
      "type": "POST",
      "dataType": "json",
      "headers": { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
      "data": function ( d ) {
       d.group = group;
       return $.extend( {}, d, {
        group: group,
        type: 'members'
       });
      },
      error: function (xhr, error, thrown) {
       console.log(xhr);
      }
     },
     
     "columns": [
      { "data": "user" },
      { "data": "rank" },
      { "data": "lastOn" },
      { "data": "activity" },
      { "data": "xyz" }
     ]
    });
   });
   
   
   
   $('.dataTables_processing').addClass('dataTables_empty');
   
   $('.dt-button').addClass('btn btn-default btn-sm');
   
   $('.tab-content div:first').addClass('active');
  });
 </script>
@endsection
```

The main file looks like so:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="fixed">
    @include('user.includes.head')
    <section id="css">
        @yield('extra_css')
    </section>
    <body>
        <section class="body">
            @include('user.layouts.navbar')
            <div class="inner-wrapper">
                @include('user.layouts.sidebar')
                <section role="main" class="content-body">
                    <header class="page-header">
                        <h2 id="title">@yield('title')</h2>
                    </header>
                    @if (session('message_error'))
                        <div class="row message">
                            <div class="col-xl-12">
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                    <strong>Error:</strong> {{ session('message_error') }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @endif
                    <div id="innerContent">
                        @yield('content')
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </section>
        @include('user.includes.footer')
        <div id="bottom_elements">
            @yield('bottom_elements')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

## What have I tried so far?

I tried to change the sequence of the loadContent function calls, however, the functionality of the bootstrap classes still did not work (such as drop-downs, etc').

## What am I looking for?

I need that when you click on the menu to load the page (groups), it will load the page and retain all the  content of it as well as the bootstrap functionality, as it does not get loaded once the content of the target page loads.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest including jQuery and bootstrap .js files in your page file, the file that is being loaded dynamically.There is possibly a better way of doing this but this works fine.